# Uploading React app to an external server

Tags: reactjs, deployment, hosting

I'm completely new in React world.

A few days ago I developed my very first simple React app, built the app and uploaded it to my GoDaddy host. I thought this would be enough as I had an index.html in the root of my host and the thought that the build will work once I open my domain in browser.

Unfortunately, it turned out that it's not working. Nothing is easy in life.

[image]

After hours of googling I found out that people upload their React apps to special services such as Heroku. I found a tutorial and managed to publish my react app successfully on Heroku. But to be honest I still don't know why my app wasn't working on GoDaddy server.

When I was preparing my app for Heroku, one step was creating a **server.js** file using **express.js**.

Does it mean that each React app needs such a server file to be working? What if I wanted to use my React app on GoDaddy or any other hosting server? Would it be possible?

Comment: Does the application have a dependency to Node.js? Or did you build it so that it can be served independently?

Comment: React app don't any server file you just need a to deploy your server on somewhere and can use this server into your app.

Comment: @Andreas, It's just a simple journey planner app that sends an API request to TFL (Transport for London) and prints the result in to UI.

Comment: @Waheed, sorry, but I don't understand. You say that React apps don't need any server file. But then you add "you need to deploy your server on somewhere". Now I'm confused.

Comment: @user1941537 do you know about axios?

Comment: @Waheed, yes. In fact I'm using Axios in my app to fetch data from TFL API. Why are you asking?

Comment: I'm really surprised that I don't get any clear answer to my question. Am I the only person that tries to host his React app on a normal shared hosting server?

Comment: You are getting error from your server where you are hitting your server there is permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out what was the problem.

It turned out that paths inside the index.html don't mirror the build folder structure.

Inside the index.html I had to change references like this:

```
/static/css/2.567.chunk.css
```

To this:

```
./static/css/2.567.chunk.css
```

And inside of CSS files I needed to change paths like this:

```
/static/media/tree.6098.jpg
```

To this:

```
../media/tree.6098.jpg
```

After that you simply upload your files and everything works as it should.

Now the question is, why those paths are not as they should be?

Comment: That just means that your build is configured wrongly

Comment: @Andreas, it could be that I'm doing something wrongly. As I mentioned, I'm new in React world. I created my app with create-react-app. Didn't change any settings. npm start works. For building the app I did npm run build. Uploaded the content of build folder to my GoDaddy shard hosting. But as mentioned before the paths to JS and CSS files inside the index.html don't mirror the build folder structure and cannot be found. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Thanks